# Connect to a mysql web database from my program

Tags: c++, mysql, c, xcode, host

I'm trying to connect to a mysql web database from my program, but I keep getting:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql7.000webhost.com' (51)
```

I'm using this website free mysql server:

> 000webhost.com

This is my code or the code I found in google to start learning.

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// just going to input the general details and not the port numbers
struct connection_details
{
    char *server;
    char *user;
    char *password;
    char *database;
};

MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details mysql_details)
{
    // first of all create a mysql instance and initialize the variables within
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    // connect to the database with the details attached.
    if (!mysql_real_connect(connection,mysql_details.server, mysql_details.user, mysql_details.password, mysql_details.database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        printf("Conection error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
        exit(1);
    }
    return connection;
}

MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connection, char *sql_query)
{
    // send the query to the database
    if (mysql_query(connection, sql_query))
    {
        printf("MySQL query error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
        exit(1);
    }

    return mysql_use_result(connection);
}

int main()
{
    MYSQL *conn;        // the connection
    MYSQL_RES *res; // the results
    MYSQL_ROW row;  // the results row (line by line)

    struct connection_details mysqlD;
    mysqlD.server = (char*)"mysql7.000webhost.com";  // where the mysql database is
    mysqlD.user =  (char*)"a1206305_test";      // the root user of mysql   
    mysqlD.password =  (char*)"testthis1"; // the password of the root user in mysql
    mysqlD.database =  (char*)"a1206305_test";  // the databse to pick

    // connect to the mysql database
    conn = mysql_connection_setup(mysqlD);

    // assign the results return to the MYSQL_RES pointer
    res = mysql_perform_query(conn, (char*) "show tables");

    printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL)
        printf("%s\n", row[0]);

    /* clean up the database result set */
    mysql_free_result(res);
    /* clean up the database link */
    mysql_close(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't it connect?

Comment: Is the database configured to allow connection from outside, e.g. not localhost?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, how can you check that? and do you know any free mysql free server? that works

Comment: maybe you should look at the faq on the website of your hoster: http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=25

Comment: It says: Remote MySQL connections are disabled for security and server performance reasons.

However remote MySQL connections will be enabled if you upgrade your account.   But is it that why it dident connect?

Comment: If you don't run your app on the same machine as the mysql-server (which i doubt) then it is most likely the case.

Comment: I downloaded: MAMP PRO, Set to connection from outside and local, but now it says  Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Is your account upgraded? If not, that would be the reason you can't connect. And if you're going to set up a test platform, set it up the same as the real platform. You won't be connecting to your remote MySQL server via a socket, so you shouldn't do so on your test platform either. Also, somewhat off-topic, but there is a Connector/C++ you can use for MySQL that will give you an OOP C++ interface instead of using the standard C interface. Don't know if it's any good or not, just know it exists. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a shared web hosting, the mysql server is probably configured to reject outside connections.